# How to set up a loop with BASH to find a directory with write permissions?

Tags: linux, bash

I am very new to Linux and shell scripting, and I'm getting stuck on a certain part of a script that I have to write.  This is for a class assignment.

I need to write a loop that will check to see if there is a users (in my group) public_html file turned on with the write switch `rwx`.  So that I can write information into it, and than go retrieve it from that group member's `public_html` after I have finished getting the information I need.

This is where I am right now:

```
while read temp;do

# this is my main hang up, to see it this global 
# switch is turned on to write.
if[[ <9> = 'w' ]] 
echo "$temp has their w switch turned on."

# this also is throwing me off, i think this is the way to 
# keep going until all the public_html directories in the 
# group have been seen.
done < ..public_html
```

or I am trying to figure out how to use the find command which seems to logically be simpiler and make more sense, i just have never used it so am kind of flying by the seat of my pants on this one I tried this line to no avail, maybe its close?

```
find . */home/public_html -perm -g +w
#I was hoping that would search all user directories looking for the permission +w turned on in public_html.
```

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like: do my assignment for me.

Comment: If you would like help with this, I would suggest showing what you've done/tried and give an explanation with the issue you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you required to do this with a loop?  This seems like a natural fit for [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).  In particular, the `-perm`, `-gid`, and `-type` tests would be useful here.

Can you explain your environment in a little more detail?  Are you looking for files named `public_html` in users' home directories?  Or are you looking for files/folders in the current directory?  Or something else entirely?

Some hints for using `find`:

- Use the `-type d` test to limit your results to folders
- Use the `-name` test to limit your results to things named 'public_html'
- Use the `-gid` test to limit your results to things that are in your group (the `id -g` command should report your group ID)
- Use the `-perm -g+w` test to limit your results to things that are group-writable

Combine all of these, and you should be able to filter out exactly what you're looking for.  The man page that I linked to has an "Examples" section at the bottom that shows how to use the various arguments.  You might also want to check out [this `find` tutorial](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) for more examples with explanation.

Comment: I am looking for public_html in users home directories, every user in my group has a public_html directory, only selected have the write permission turned on, but every member has the hidden information that I am looking for, so once I find a one with write permissions than I can create a .txt file in their directory and start writing the information I want, and than be able to extract my .txt file at a later time.  I will have to research how the find works, as being so new to this language I havent seen all the tricks of the trade.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the group, the dirs will be readable by you.

```
shopt -s globstar

for i in **/*/; do
    test -x "$i" && echo "$i have 'x' bit"
done
```

Require `bash --version` >=4